# Text underline detection causes an error - why?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, runtime-error, text-decorations

I followed this tutorial to create a rich text editor: [How-to: Creating a Rich Text Editor](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/rich-text-controls/how-to-creating-a-rich-text-editor/)

Bold and Italic works as expected, but underline throws an error. I don´t understand why and hope for someone to throw some light on this!

Togglebuttons inside a Toolbar and RichTextBox:

```
<ToolBar>
    <ToggleButton Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" Name="btnBold" Height="25" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="F" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
    <ToggleButton Command="EditingCommands.ToggleItalic" Name="btnItalic" Height="25" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="K" FontStyle="Oblique"/>
    <ToggleButton Visibility="Hidden" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline" Name="btnUnderline" Height="25" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ToggleButton.Content>
            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="U"/>
        </ToggleButton.Content>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ComboBox Name="cmbFontSize" Height="20" Width="50" IsEditable="True" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="cmbFontSize_TextChanged" />
</ToolBar>
<RichTextBox Name="rtbEditor" SelectionChanged="rtbEditor_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Sub to use the buttons:

```
Public Sub rtbEditor_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim temp As Object = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontWeightProperty)
    btnBold.IsChecked = (temp <> Nothing) AndAlso (temp.Equals(FontWeights.Bold))
    temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontStyleProperty)
    btnItalic.IsChecked = (temp <> Nothing) AndAlso (temp.Equals(FontStyles.Italic))
    temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty)
    btnUnderline.IsChecked = (temp <> DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) AndAlso (temp.Equals(TextDecorations.Underline))

    temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontSizeProperty)
    cmbFontSize.Text = temp.ToString()
End Sub
```

This throws an error:

```
btnUnderline.IsChecked = (temp <> DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) AndAlso (temp.Equals(TextDecorations.Underline))
```

Error message (translated from swedish):

> operator <> not defined for type TextDecorationCollection and NamedObject

Why??

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Comment: Sorry, had that in the title first but got no viewers. Then I forgot to add it to my question.

It trows something like this, loosely translated from swedish: operator <> not defined for type textdecorationcollection and NamedObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
if blubb isNot nothing
End if
```

instead of:

```
if blubb <> nothing
End if
```

your code:

```
Public Sub rtbEditor_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

Dim temp As Object = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontWeightProperty)
btnBold.IsChecked = (temp isNot Nothing) AndAlso (temp.Equals(FontWeights.Bold))
temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontStyleProperty)
btnItalic.IsChecked = (temp isNot Nothing) AndAlso (temp.Equals(FontStyles.Italic))
temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty)
btnUnderline.IsChecked = (temp isNot DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) AndAlso (temp.Equals(TextDecorations.Underline))

temp = rtbEditor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontSizeProperty)
cmbFontSize.Text = temp.ToString()

End Sub
```

Comment: Ha! That simple? Thought I tried that but apperently not! Thank you very much. /Christian

Comment: The simplest are the hardest ones :P